# Ordenar ficheiros por nome c#

Tags: c#, classificação

Tenho vários ficheiros assim:

```
- C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\1_CREATE_TABLE_BMTApprovalGroupExam.sql
- C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\10_CREATE_PROC_BMSPInsertNewApprovalRequest2.sql
- C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\11_CREATE_PROC_BMSPUpdateApprovalRequest2.sql 
- C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\2_CREATE_PROC_BMSPInsertNewApprovalGroupExam.sql
```

Preciso de ordenar os ficheiros assim em C#:

```
- C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\1_CREATE_TABLE_BMTApprovalGroupExam.sql
- C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\2_CREATE_PROC_BMSPInsertNewApprovalGroupExam.sql
- C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\10_CREATE_PROC_BMSPInsertNewApprovalRequest2.sql
- C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\11_CREATE_PROC_BMSPUpdateApprovalRequest2.sql
```

Fiz assim:

```
string[] sqlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (string file in sqlFiles.OrderBy(file => file)) { }
```

Mas não está a dar certo. Está a executar pelo primeiro passo que eu tenho.

Comment: É certo que a primeira coisa do nome do arquivo vai ser um número? E sempre vai ter um underline depois?

Comment: Sim é certo. A primeira coisa do nome vai ser o número.

Comment: @AnaCarvalho caso o número seja repetido, a ordem lexicográfica deve ser o critério de desempate?

Comment: se o nome dos arquivos fossem 01, 02, 10 e 11 facilitaria a ordenação =]

Comment: Pois era, mas como é para o meu trabalho, isso já está definido desde o inicio.

Comment: Bom dia Ana. Por favor, você poderia [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar a informação sobre o caminho completo do arquivo? Isso muda totalmente o teor das respostas que poderiam surgir.

Comment: Já corrigi a pergunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguindo a resposta do @jbueno, você pode utilizar o [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) para retornar somente o nome do arquivo, e seguir com a ordenação com o `.Split('_')[0]`, para utilizar somente os números.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
var sqlFiles = new[] { @" C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\20170405_TR\1_CREATE_TABLE_BMTApprovalGroupExam.sql",
                       @" C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\2‌0170405_TR\10_CREATE_PROC_BMSPInsertNewApprovalRequest2.sql",
                       @" C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\2‌0170405_TR\11_CREATE_PROC_BMSPUpdateApprovalRequest2.sql",
                       @" C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\2‌0170405_TR\2_CREATE_PROC_BMSPInsertNewApprovalGroupExam.sql" };

foreach (string file in sqlFiles.OrderBy(file => Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_')[0])))

{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N3IraF)

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigada :)

Answer (score 0):

Para ajudar quem precisar, a resposta à pergunta já resolvida fica da seguinte forma:

```
    string[] sqlFilesLocation = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
 foreach (string file in sqlFilesLocation.OrderBy(file => Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_')[0])))
```