# Remover metade do nome do ficheiro

Tags: c#, .net, string

Tenho uma página para ir buscar um caminho, que é o `Folder Browser Dialog` e o caminho que é guardado está assim : "C:\ana\Updates\2017\2017_04\"

Queria através desde caminho, guardar numa variável apenas o resultado : 2017\2017_04.

Comment: É qual é o critério para a escolha do que deve pegar? É os 2 últimos, é tudo o que vem depois do quinto nível. É depois de um determinado nome? è por um padrão específico?

Comment: Depois de um determinado nome, que neste caso é o "updates"

Comment: Olá Ana,
Se a dúvida tem a ver com [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208324/20615), poste o caminho completo para evitar transtornos. Caso esse seja o caminho completo, desconsidere essa mensagem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você quer capturar só o que vem depois de "Updates", como foi dito nos comentários é só capturar a posição em que a palavra chave ("updates", no caso) se encontra dentro do caminho completo e trabalhar em um *substring*.

Note que o segundo parâmetro de `LastIndexOf` faz com que o *casing* seja ignorado na comparação. Se não quiser este comportamento, é só remover este parâmetro.

```
string palavraChave = "Updates";
var dir = @"C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\";

var index = dir.LastIndexOf(palavraChave, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

var resultado = dir.Substring(index + palavraChave.Length + 1);

Console.WriteLine(resultado);

// A saída será 2017\2017_04\
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m87bBT)

Answer (score 7):

Uma solução ingênua seria usar o [`Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads). Na verdade qualquer solução que tente achar um padrão de texto corre o risco de dar errado a não ser que tenha garantias do que vai encontrar ou o critério seja muito bem definido, resolvendo todas ambiguidades possíveis. Seria melhor se pudesse garantir o começo inteiro sendo igual, aí em vez de filtrar por `\Updates` poderia filtrar por `C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\` que aí não haverá risco. Mesmo se variar uma parte seria melhor construir este texto todo só com a parte que varia diferente.

Provavelmente não é do seu interesse, mas em alguns casos generalizar o separador pode ser útil para o código ser mais portável. Veja o [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Não para este caso, mas mantenha atenção na classe [`Path`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) quando estiver lidando com caminhos de arquivos, tem muita coisa pronta e mais bem feita que a maioria dos programadores conseguem fazer.

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var dir = @"C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\2017\2017_04\";
        var partes = dir.Split(new string[] { @"\Updates\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        WriteLine(partes[1]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/a66MzV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nqF39T).  Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitDirectory.cs).